# Create a function that opens a file and creates a dictionary

Tags: python, function, dictionary

I have a file that I'm working with.  I want to create a function that reads the files and place the contents into a dictionary. Then that dictionary needs to be passed through the main function.  Here is the main program.  It cannot be changed. Everything I do must work with the main program.

```
def main():
    sunspot_dict = {}
    file_str = raw_input("Open what data file: ")
    keep_going = True
    while keep_going:
        try:
            init_dictionary(file_str, sunspot_dict)
        except IOError:
            print "Data file error, try again"
            file_str = raw_input("Open what data file: ")    
            continue
        print "Jan, 1900-1905:", avg_sunspot(sunspot_dict, (1900,1905),(1,1))
        print "Jan-June, 2000-2011:", avg_sunspot(sunspot_dict, (2000,2011), (1,6))
        print "All years, Jan:", avg_sunspot(sunspot_dict, month_tuple=(1,1))
        print "All months, 1900-1905:", avg_sunspot(sunspot_dict, year_tuple=(1900,1905))
        try:
            print "Bad Year Key example:", avg_sunspot(sunspot_dict, (100,1000), (1,1))
        except KeyError:
            print "Bad Key raised"
        try:
            print "Bad Month Index example:", avg_sunspot(sunspot_dict, (2000,2011), (1,100))
        except IndexError:
            print "Bad Range raised"
        keep_going = False
    print "Main function finished normally."

    print sunspot_dict
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
def init_dictionary(file_str, sunspot_dict):
    line = open(file_str, "rU")
    sunspot_dict = {}
    for i in line:
        sunspot_dict[i]
print sunspot_dict
```

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I am not sure how to proceed.  Maybe I am understanding the problem wrong.  Here is what the assignment says:

init_dictionary(file_string, sunspot_dict). This function takes as an argument the name of file to open and an empty dictionary. It has no return value but does fill the dictionary with values. The key should be the year; the data should be a list of sunspot data for the months of that year.

Is it saying to use the __init__ function to do this under a class?  Or should I just create a normal function named init_dictionary(file_string, sunspot_dict)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your second comment and your preview code, you are on the right track. Dictionaries in Python are passed by reference, so you should just be able to fill the dictionary provided to `init_dictionary` and the values will be accessible in `main()`. In your case you are creating a new dictionary in `init_dictionary` with the line `sunspot_dict = {}`. You don't want to do this, because the dictionary you want to use was already created in `main()`.

At this point we would need to know the format of the file you are reading. Basically you need to open the file, then probably read it line by line while parsing the lines into key/value pairs and filling `sunspot_dict`.

Comment: It is just a text file.  

                          MONTHLY MEAN SUNSPOT NUMBERS                         
====================================================================
Year    Jan   Feb   Mar   Apr   May   Jun   Jul   Aug   Sep   Oct   Nov   Dec  
--------------------------------------------------------------------
1749    58.0  62.6  70.0  55.7  85.0  83.5  94.8  66.3  75.9  75.5 158.6  85.2

I have turned the years into keys and the numbers following into values.  Now I need to strip everything but the digits.  Any idea on the best way to do that?

Comment: From there I need to create tuples.  One for the years and another for the months.  This is for the purpose of the user entering an amount of time and getting an average.

Comment: Did you write the `avg_sunspot` function? Looks like it takes your dictionary, then two tuples: one that says the range of years to average, and the other the range of months. If you have trouble with writing that function you should make a new question.

Comment: For your dictionary though, I think you are close. It should use the year as the key, then have a list of numbers (12 of them) for the value. I don't know what you mean by "strip everything but the digits" but you probably want to use [`split()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) and `float(str)`.

Comment: I was able to figure out how to get only digits by using .isdigit() and putting only those values into the dictionary.  As for this function:
avg_sunspot(sunspot_dict, year_tuple, month_tuple):

It asks for 3 arguments.  If someone gives only two arguments, I want the default to just give the average for all the years.  How do I go about setting the default?

Comment: You're looking for [default argument values](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#default-argument-values)

Answer (score 1):

Given the restriction you give in your reply to Raymond, that you can't modify the `init_dictionary()` method and that it requires that you pass it a dictionary which it will then populate, I recommend that you make your own class a subclass of `dict`.

```
class MySunspotDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, file_str):
        init_dictionary(file_str, self)

    # ... define your other methods here

sunspot_dict = MySunspotDict(file_str)
```

The `sunspot_dict = MySunspotDict(file_str)` line goes where you currently have `init_dictionary(file_str, sunspot_dict)`, so your existing `file_str` is passed to the `MySunspotDict` constructor (`__init__()` method), which will then pass it to `init_dictionary()`.

The `init_dictionary()` call works the same as the one you already have, except it passes the new object rather than an empty `dict` to the function that populates the dictionary. Since your new class is derived from `dict`, i.e. it is a subclass, it works just like a regular dictionary for this purpose. So what you have is basically a `dict` that you can attach your own methods to. (You can also override some of the standard dictionary behavior by defining methods with special names, but you shouldn't need to do that in this case.)

Note that in your methods, `self` will be the dictionary -- you don't need to create the dictionary in your `__init__()` and store it as an attribute of your class (you will see this pattern in a lot of Python code). The dictionary already exists by the time `__init__()` runs.

Comment: Since the main function is asking the user for the name of the file, how can I connect that with the class that I am creating?  From your example the main function would go outside of the the MySunspotDict class right?  Can you explain the following part of the code to me? 

    init_dictionary(file_str, self)

Comment: Added some additional clarification.

Comment: "The sunspot_dict = MySunspotDict(file_str) line goes where you currently have init_dictionary(file_str, sunspot_dict)"

Are you trying to say change it from the main function under the while loop?  
    while keep_going:
            try:
                init_dictionary(file_str, sunspot_dict)
            except IOError:
I can't change anything from the main function.  The code I write has to work with the main function.  I need to read the file that the user inputs from the main function and put the data into a dictionary.

Comment: I'm sorry if I am not understanding your explanation.  I'm just having a lot of trouble understanding classes.

Comment: Whoops, this is my error. I thought you couldn't modify the `init_dicitonary()` function. If you can't modify your `main()` function, I can't see a reasonable way to do what you want. Changing your program to be object-oriented generally requires that you be able to *change your program,* usually quite substantially.

Comment: Ok I understand.  Now is it possible to accomplish what I need without a class?  Do you have any examples of doing this with just functions?  I still can't change the main function, but work around it with other functions.  My biggest problem is how do I read a file, create the dictionary, then pass it through the main function as well.  Thanks a bunch for the help.

Comment: Well, the `main()` function is written so that it does the file-reading and dictionary-creating itself. It's not designed to accept an already-created dictionary. So, you would need to change that function (or replace it entirely with your own code).