# Making a dictionary from a file

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create a function that opens a file and creates a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8117441/create-a-function-that-opens-a-file-and-creates-a-dictionary)

We are given a main function to use to:

Write the following two functions:

1. `init_dictionary(file_string, sunspot_dict)`
   This function takes as an argument the name of file to open and an empty dictionary. It has no return value but does fill the dictionary with values. The key should be the year; the data should be a list of sunspot data for the months of that year.

The main function is:

```
def main():
sunspot_dict = {}
file_str = raw_input("Open what data file: ")
keep_going = True
while keep_going:
    try:
        init_dictionary(file_str, sunspot_dict)
    except IOError:
        print "Data file error, try again"
        file_str = raw_input("Open what data file: ")    
        continue
    print "Jan, 1900-1905:", avg_sunspot(sunspot_dict, (1900,1905),(1,1))
    print "Jan-June, 2000-2011:", avg_sunspot(sunspot_dict, (2000,2011), (1,6))
    print "All years, Jan:", avg_sunspot(sunspot_dict, month_tuple=(1,1))
    print "All months, 1900-1905:", avg_sunspot(sunspot_dict, year_tuple=(1900,1905))
    try:
        print "Bad Year Key example:", avg_sunspot(sunspot_dict, (100,1000), (1,1))
    except KeyError:
        print "Bad Key raised"
    try:
        print "Bad Month Index example:", avg_sunspot(sunspot_dict, (2000,2011), (1,100))
    except IndexError:
        print "Bad Range raised"
    keep_going = False
print "Main function finished normally."
```

I have no idea where to start! Please help!

The file were given is the months on the x axis and the years from 1749-2011 with numbers filling it

Comment: "I have no idea where to start!" You need to start somewhere, so start with opening and reading the file (search for how to do file I/O in Python, if you do not know how). Once you hit a concrete problem, ask a question, and with luck, someone might be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Read more about IO in Python ....

You need to open the file , extract its contents and then populate your dictionary...

Have a look at [Input-Output in Python](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html)

A hint is to look at this example where they try to make a dictionary out of a file ....  [reading file to dictionary](http://python.about.com/b/2007/04/03/a-python-function-to-read-a-file-into-a-dictionary.htm)

Comment: I need the year to be the key in the year and the value to be the data, here is some of the txt file:

MONTHLY MEAN SUNSPOT NUMBERS                         
===============================================================================
Year    Jan   Feb   Mar   Apr   May   Jun   Jul   Aug   Sep   Oct   Nov   Dec  
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1749    58.0  62.6  70.0  55.7  85.0  83.5  94.8  66.3  75.9  75.5 158.6  85.2
1750    73.3  75.9  89.2  88.3  90.0 100.0  85.4 103.0  91.2  65.7  63.3  75.4

Comment: First write the code for reading and writing the file... Then it will become obvious to you ... making the dictionary is not difficult parsing the file data is .. so do that first

Comment: file_str = raw_input("What file to open:")


def init_dictionary(file_str, sunspot_dict):
    line = open(file_str, "rU")
    sunspot_dict = {}
    for i in line:
        sunspot_dict[i]
        print sunspot_dict

Comment: do it like this ... data = line.readlines() after reading the file.. Now data contains each line of the file ... Do a for loop in data and parse the elements as you want ...